# Why does eclipse keeps highlighting a method?

Tags: android, eclipse, syntax-highlighting

I am trying to override the method onItemClick. I will put my imports and methods below:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Contacts.People;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class ListViewActivityActivity extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener {

    @Override 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView adview, View target, int position, long id) {}

}
```

My question is why does **onItemClick** method keep underlining? What am I doing wrong? 
I tried reloading project and it didn't help. Anybody run in to the same problem?

PS when I hover over it it says : The method onItemClick(AdapterView, View, int, long) of type ListViewActivityActivity must override a superclass method

Comment: Hum, was it the last thing you search for? If so search for something random, to make it not highlight.

Comment: No, its indicating there is an error.

Comment: what does eclipse say if you hover over the underlined method? what does it say if you Ctrl+1 on it?

Comment: Also, do you have any kind of message in the "problems view"?

Comment: Let me guess... project's Java compiler level is set to "1.5"?

Comment: What does the error say? Mouse over it and press F2. Sometimes when eclipse isn't being clear i will compile and see what compilers says.

Comment: It says : The method onItemClick(AdapterView<?>, View, int, long) of type ListViewActivityActivity must override a superclass method

Comment: Either you're not passing the same method arguments or not throwing the same exceptions. Method signatures must match 100%.

Comment: It says : The method onItemClick(AdapterView<?>, View, int, long) of type ListViewActivityActivity must override a superclass method

Comment: Yeah, I checked, I pass the same arguments and receive the same.

Comment: Found it! I had to remove @Override from the code. I don't understand how the code work without that. But it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your project has the Java compiler level set to 1.5. The `@Override` annotation is not allowed for a class implementing an interface method in Java 1.5; this is only allowed from Java 1.6 onward.

Go into your project properties (project's context menu), select `Java Compiler` and set the compiler compliance level to 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the non-generic type of `AdapterView` but the original method uses a generic type. It is allowed by the compiler, but not recommended.

This is the right way to override `onItemClick` :

```
@Override 
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adview, View target, int position, long id) {}
```

Comment: Found it!! Somehow you have to remove the @Override from the code. I dont understand how it works without overriding. But it works!

Comment: No, you don't have to remove the annotation.