# Eclipse Indigo does not allow @Override for non Activity overwritten methods

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using Eclipse Indigo for Android development. The problem i face is that it does not allow @Override for non Activity overwritten methods. For example if i implement onErrorListner of MediaPlayer and i set attribute @Override with it then it gives the following compile time error:

```
The method onError(MediaPlayer, int, int) of type MyActivity must override a superclass method
```

And to fix this problem, i am suggested the following

```
Remove "@Override" annotation
```

Tough removing the @Override fixes the issue but why does it complain about it and also removing it may cause stopping some functionality of its parent etc??

I have downloaded many examples which use this "@Override" attribute with non-activity methods which proves that this is used and i might be missing some obvious thing. But i cannot run these examples in Eclipse Indigo without removing these "@Override" attributes from all the classes.

Why?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: your source compatibility is set to 1.5, in 1.5 you can only override methods in Classes - not Interfaces. On your Eclipse project, select "Properties" in the context menu, select "Java Compiler" and check the "Enable project specific settings". Change "Compiler compliance level" to 1.6 and rebuild your project.

Comment: right click android project -> goto android tools -> then fix project properties.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your project Java compiler level is set to 1.5 instead of 1.6. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213421/why-does-eclipse-keeps-highlighting-a-method/9219594#9219594).

Comment: Hi! I have the same problem, but my java compiler was set to 1.7. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does the Android SDK actually work with Java level 1.7? Just set it to 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

It is not good to remove that line. you need to change to JDK version in your eclipse then you will not get such errors. Follow, following steps for it,

Right Click on your Project & select Properties.

Then from the left section Select Java Compiler & select the Version of the JDK you installed. If it is already selected then de-select it & try it.